# Como centrar el contenido de mi web

Tags: html, css

necesito central el contenido de mi web, pero quiero que sea automatico y no definirle los pixeles al margen, para evitar que alguien con un monitor más pequeño o más grande lo vea de manera diferente.

Mi web es la siguiente :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* user-select: none; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  display: inline;
  place-items: center;
  background: #dde1e7;
  text-align: center;
}
.content{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 330px;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 7px #ffffff73,
               2px 2px 5px rgba(94,104,121,0.288);
}
.content .text{
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: #595959;
}
.field{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.field:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.field input{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 45px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  color: #595959;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
              inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
.field input:focus{
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #BABECC,
              inset -1px -1px 2px #ffffff73;
}
.field span{
  position: absolute;
  color: #595959;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.field label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 45px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #666666;
}
.field input:valid ~ label{
  opacity: 0;
}
.forgot-pass{
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;
}
.forgot-pass a{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forgot-pass:hover a{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button{
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #595959;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
             -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
button:focus{
  color: #3498db;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
             inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
.sign-up{
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sign-up a{
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sign-up a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.volver-atras{
  padding-left: 23px;
  display: flex;
  width: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="text">Modo Invitado</div>
<form action="#">
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" required>
          <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
          <label>Nombre de Usuario</label>
        </div>
        <button>Iniciar Sesion</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <button class="volver-atras">
      <i data-feather="corner-up-left"></i>
      </button>
</body>
<script>
  feather.replace();
</script>
</html>
```

He conseguido alinearlo al centro horizontalmente, pero quiero centrarlo también verticalmente.
He intentado simplemente modificar el .content margin 0, subiendo pixeles y obviamente se cambia, pero no quiero tener que definirle esos pixeles a mano.
Probé a cambiar el display del body a grid, pero me deja mucho espacio entre el volver atras y el contenido, queda algo así:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* user-select: none; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #dde1e7;
  text-align: center;
}
.content{
  width: 330px;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 7px #ffffff73,
               2px 2px 5px rgba(94,104,121,0.288);
}
.content .text{
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: #595959;
}
.field{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.field:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.field input{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 45px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  color: #595959;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
              inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
.field input:focus{
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #BABECC,
              inset -1px -1px 2px #ffffff73;
}
.field span{
  position: absolute;
  color: #595959;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.field label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 45px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #666666;
}
.field input:valid ~ label{
  opacity: 0;
}
.forgot-pass{
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;
}
.forgot-pass a{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forgot-pass:hover a{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button{
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #595959;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
             -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
button:focus{
  color: #3498db;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
             inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}
.sign-up{
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sign-up a{
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sign-up a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.volver-atras{
  padding-left: 23px;
  display: flex;
  width: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="text">Modo Invitado</div>
<form action="#">
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" required>
          <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
          <label>Nombre de Usuario</label>
        </div>
        <button>Iniciar Sesion</button>
  </form>
    </div>
    <button class="volver-atras">
      <i data-feather="corner-up-left"></i>
      </button>
</body>
<script>
  feather.replace();
</script>
</html>
```

Para apreciar la diferencia ejecutar el codigo en pantalla completa.
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arreglemos un poco tu código. No es recomendable posicionar el elemento a través de la etiqueta `body`, ya que si tienes más elementos en tu página, también les afectaría:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: #dde1e7;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Borramos todo esto y dejemos solo el `background`, que sería justo lo necesario para el `body`:

```
body { background: #dde1e7; }
```

Ahora para centrar tu login y botón, como buenas prácticas, hay que crear un `div` padre que encierre a estos dos elementos, llamado `contenido`:

```
<div class="contenido">
  <div class="content">
    <!-- todo tu login -->
  </div>
  <button class="volver-atras">
    <!-- tu botón -->
  </button>
</div>
```

Luego centramos al `contenido` (que encierra al login y al botón) con las siguientes propiedades:

```
.contenido {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Aquí solo hago que los elementos sean flexibles, estén alineados en columnas, tenga una altura de `100vh`, y en esa altura, los elementos se alinearán al centro con `align-items: center` y también justificados al centro con `justify-content: center;` ([**más formas de centrar un div**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/como-centrar-un-div-con-css-10-maneras-diferentes/)).

---

Código completo:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* user-select: none; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #dde1e7;
}

.contenido {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  width: 330px;
  padding: 30px 30px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 7px #ffffff73,
    2px 2px 5px rgba(94,104,121,0.288);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.content .text {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: #595959;
}

.field {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.field:nth-child(2)  {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.field input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 45px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #dde1e7;
  color: #595959;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
    inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}

.field input:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #BABECC,
    inset -1px -1px 2px #ffffff73;
}

.field span {
  position: absolute;
  color: #595959;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.field label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 45px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #666666;
}

.field input:valid ~ label {
  opacity: 0;
}

.forgot-pass {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;
}

.forgot-pass a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.forgot-pass:hover a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button {
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #dde1e7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #595959;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
    -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}

button:focus {
  color: #3498db;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #BABECC,
    inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
}

.sign-up {
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sign-up a {
  color: #3498db;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sign-up a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.volver-atras {
  padding-left: 23px;
  display: flex;
  width: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contenido">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="text">Modo Invitado</div>
        <form action="#">
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text" required>
            <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            <label>Nombre de Usuario</label>
          </div>
          <button>Iniciar Sesion</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <button class="volver-atras">
        <i data-feather="corner-up-left"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    feather.replace();
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas graciias por la respuesta y aclaración :)

Answer (score -1):

para poder alinear de manera correctar todo lo que hay dentro de los div's, es preferible usar display:flex, e ir jugando un poco con el justify-content, y el align_content. suerte :D

Comment: He probado a modificar el display en el body que es donde lo tengo, y los otros parametros no hacen nada

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos.